# Angular4 Change Detection ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

I'm trying to solve a problem, that didn't exist in AngularJS, due to the `$digest`-cycle checking everything.

I'm trying to create a component, that can initialize itself (async) and notify its surrounding container that the loading has been completed.

I have this pseudo-table:

```html
<my-table>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let row in rows">
        <my-table-row
            [row]="row"
            [isLoading]="row.isLoading"
            (click)="onClickRow(row)"
        ></my-table-row>
        <my-detail-row *ngIf="row.isExpanded">
            <my-component
                [data]="row"
            ></my-component>
        ></my-detail-row>
    </ng-container>
</my-table>
```

In the surrounding component (that holds the `rows`), I have the function `onClickRow(row)` which toggles `row.isExpanded`.

In the `my-component` component I want to set `row.isLoading` to true (notifying the "parent" row that it is loading) and then setting it to false after the API call is completed.

```ts
@Input() data: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.task.isLoading = true; // PROBLEM

    setTimeout(() => { // simulate API call
        this.task.isLoading = false; // no problem
    }, 2000);
}
```

Now I get this error: `Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'true'.`

I guess this is because the change goes from `my-component` up the tree to `ng-container` but then not down to `my-table-row`?

I have a workaround, in that I can use a second `setTimeout()`, around the first setting of `this.task.isLoading`, but this leads to some popin-effects and I would like to find a cleaner solution if possible.

Does anyone have a suggestion, how this can work?

Comment: [Everything you need to know about the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) explains this behavior in great details

Comment: why not always initialize with `task.isLoading=true` and not set it from the my-component but then only update to `false` when component is loaded, this will be done async as you say and you will not have this problem

Comment: @Maximus I can't put `isLoading=true` as default, it controls the visible behaviour of the `my-table-row` (shows a loading indicator). The link has been helpful, but kinda tells me, I have no choice other than Promise/Timeout to do this, because I'm doing something that I shouldn't really do. But right now I cannot think of any other way to accomplish this with having a "dumb" table/wrapping-component with all the logic in the `my-component` child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that I can live with.

You can inject the "parent" into your component (similar to `require` in AngularJS).

For this to work, you need to combine `my-table-row`and `my-detail-row` into something like `my-item-row`. This has the added benefit, that you can put the toggling-logic into the component and don't have to re-implement it on every use.

`my-item-row.component.html`:

```
<div
    class="item-row"
    (click)="onToggleDetail()"
>
    <div class="cell">...</div>

    <div *ngIf="isLoading" class="loading"></div>
</div>

<div
    *ngIf="isExpanded"
    [hidden]="!isInitialized"
    class="detail-row"
>
    ...
</div>
```

`my-item-row.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Input, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class MyItemRowComponent {
    ...

    isInitialized: boolean = false;
    isLoading: boolean = false;
    isExpanded: boolean = false;

    constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    onToggleDetail() : void {
        this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
    }

    public startLoading() : void {
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.isInitialized = false;

        this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); // trigger re-evaluate
    }

    public stopLoading() : void {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.isInitialized = true;

        this.changeDetector.detectChanges(): // trigger re-evaluate
    }
}
```

Now, you can inject this into `my-component`, like this:

`my-component.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Input, Host, Optional } from '@angular/core';

import { MyItemRowComponent } from '...';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponentComponent {
    ...

    // Optional, because there may be a case where we want to use it outside of a row
    constructor(@Optional() @Host() private parent: MyItemRowComponent) { }

    ngOnInit() { // or ngAfterViewInit, doesn't matter
        if (this.parent) {
            this.parent.startLoading();
        }

        setTimeout(() => { // simulate API call
            if (this.parent) {
                this.parent.stopLoading();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

This is my current solution.

This lead to a different issue with the `my-component` being initiated, even when it wasn't expanded yet, see here:

[Angular4 ng-content gets built when ngIf is false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929726/angular4-ng-content-gets-built-when-ngif-is-false/44929978#44929978)